# Request.user gives anonymous user in JWT

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

In my django rest framework project I used json web tocken based authentication and custom user model I want to access requested user object to pass as foreign key when I try **`request.user`** it will return AnonymousaUser

#### views.py

```py
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
@api_view(["POST"])
def createAppoinment(req):
   data=req.data
   serializer=AppoinmentSerializer(data=req.data)
   if serializer.is_valid():

      serializer.save(owner=req.user)   
      return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
   return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

#### I get the following error

```bash
ValueError: Cannot assign "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x000002894FE58A00>": "Appoinment.owner" must be a "NewUser" instance.
```

#### settings.py

```py
"""
Django settings for minaAssist project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
from datetime import timedelta


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-9lyg4w$982%q6am+mu@up154gwcam*ok22#a39xx6beg#(a^5@'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
    "corsheaders",


    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',


]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ), 'DATE_INPUT_FORMATS': ["%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z", "%Y-%m-%d %H", "%Y-%m-%d %HT%H:%M:%S.%f%z"],
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': '%Y-%m-%d %H',
    'DATE_FORMAT': '%Y-%m-%d %H'
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'minaAssist.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'minaAssist.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'api.NewUser'


...

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=15),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=5),
    "ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS": True,
    "BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION": True,
    "UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN": False,

    "ALGORITHM": "HS256",
    "VERIFYING_KEY": "",
    "AUDIENCE": None,
    "ISSUER": None,
    "JSON_ENCODER": None,
    "JWK_URL": None,
    "LEEWAY": 0,

    "AUTH_HEADER_TYPES": ("Bearer",),
    "AUTH_HEADER_NAME": "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION",
    "USER_ID_FIELD": "id",
    "USER_ID_CLAIM": "user_id",
    "USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE": "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule",

    "AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES": ("rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken",),
    "TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM": "token_type",
    "TOKEN_USER_CLASS": "rest_framework_simplejwt.models.TokenUser",

    "JTI_CLAIM": "jti",

    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM": "refresh_exp",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=15),
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),

    "TOKEN_OBTAIN_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenObtainPairSerializer",
    "TOKEN_REFRESH_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenRefreshSerializer",
    "TOKEN_VERIFY_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenVerifySerializer",
    "TOKEN_BLACKLIST_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenBlacklistSerializer",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_OBTAIN_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenObtainSlidingSerializer",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenRefreshSlidingSerializer",
}

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

How can I get **`request.user`** at views in JWT drf and react project

Comment: Share your authentication code, JWT decoding logic and the view in question then we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change **`request`** instead of **`req`**
here **`request`** argument handled standard **`HTTP REQUEST like(POST,GET,PUT,PATCH,DELETE)`**

```
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
@api_view(["POST"])
def createAppoinment(request):
   serializer=AppoinmentSerializer(data=request.data)
   if serializer.is_valid():

    serializer.save(owner=request.user)   
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
   return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: this does not matter, my question is not directly linked accessing the user in the view, but in the middleware, it shows as an anonymous user when using jwt but shows as a proper user object when using session